# jQuery attribute selector - am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var selector = "ul.lower-menu li a[innerText=\"" + PanelSettings[tab_name_key] + "\"]";
```

I'm trying to get horizontal menu tab that has innerText property set to the previously stored value.

The config value is stored like this:

```
PanelSettings[tab_name_key] = $("ul.lower-menu li:first > a").prop("innerText");
```

It is actually there and it always has the proper value.

I get nothing from jQuery - am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Edit: I'm using jQuery 1.6.4

Comment: The "innerText" property can't be used in selectors like that, to my knowledge. That selector syntax is for **attributes**, not properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are doing something wrong. The attribute selector selects elements that have a certain **attribute** set. `innerText` is a **property**, not an attribute – as indeed you recognise by using `prop` to set it.

You have two options. One is to use the `:contains` selector:

```
"ul.lower-menu li a:contains(" + PanelSettings[tab_name_key] + ")"
```

This, however, would select `foobar` if you asked for `foo`.  The better option is to do the filtering yourself, using `filter`:

```
var selector = "ul.lower-menu li a";
var els = $(selector).filter(function() {
    return $.text([this]) === PanelSettings[tab_name_key];
});
```

This selects only the elements whose text content is the same as the setting given.

NB also, as Diodeus says, you should use `text()` rather than `prop('innerText')`.

Comment: `$.text([this])`? you surely mean `$(this).text()`

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the difference between property and attribute. I need to read something about it.

Comment: @Einacio `$.text([this])` is an undocumented but much faster way of doing `$(this).text()` because it doesn't involve making a jQuery selection unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try `filter` instead of the attribute selector, which IMHO borders on the abusive in this case:

```
var selector = "ul.lower-menu li a";
var $links = $(selector).filter(function() {
                 return $(this).text() == PanelSettings[tab_name_key];
             });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. +1 from me, but lonesomeday's answer is more thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
.prop("innerText");
```

use:

```
 .text()
```

Comment: this is more a comment on good practices that an answer to the question about selectors

Comment: Then the problem may be the selector. See if you get any results: alert($("ul.lower-menu li:first > a").length)

Comment: I use "Firebug like" tool in opera and console.debug to see what I get. It's much better than using alert while debugging js. This actually works in all browsers (IE, FF, Opera, Chrome). Chrome and Opera have this built in while in IE and FF you need to install the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use the :contains(text) jQuery selector?

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

well, it is an attribute selector, not a property selector. you can't use selectors like that. use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with the function() variant instead